# Batch File to start application restarts itself again and again

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch script to activate a conda environment and start an application within it (which has been previously installed).
But for whatever reason, the application doesn't start but the batch script itself restarts again and again.

I'm using the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Activate Environment ...
call activate ENV

ECHO Start application ...
ApplicationName

PAUSE
```

The output if I start the batch script by doubleclicking it is:

```
Activate Environment ...    
Start application ...
Activate Environment ...    
Start application ...
Activate Environment ...    
Start application ...
```

I also tried with `call ApplicationName` and `start ApplicationName` but this doesn't work either. The application I would like to start is an own application which can be installed via pip (Python application, entrypoint specified in setup.py).

The normal use is to open a cmd or the Anaconda prompt, activate the environment manually and enter the command `ApplicationName` on the command line. After this the application triggers a browser window to open a login screen. When I use the application like that the command line window stays open during the execution of my application and prints debug messages.

I just don't understand why the commands are repeated again and again instead of that the application is started.
Do you know what causes the behaviour?

Thank you in advance for an answer!
Best Regards

Comment: Obviously, your batch file has the same name as your undisclosed *ApplicationName*

Comment: OMG this was the fastet solution for one of my problems I posed in Stackoverflow ever! :D And I feel ashamed somehow now. But thank you a lot for bringing me up to that!! You can add this is an answer if you like. Otherwise I will answer it myself...Thank you again!

Comment: Append the file extension like `application.exe` to define what file is started; otherwise, the first matching extension is taken from the environment variable `%PATHEXT%`, where `.bat` and `.cmd` usually appear before `.exe`…

Comment: If you would have used in your batch file `"%~dp0ApplicationName.exe"` to reference the executable with full qualified file name instead of using just `ApplicationName` and let `cmd.exe` search for a file using the environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH`, you would not have ever this problem on naming your batch file `ApplicationName.bat` or `ApplicationName.cmd` and Windows command processor could a little bit more quickly run the executable.

Comment: Thanks to all. I just renamed my bat file as it didn't matter :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your batch file has the same name as your undisclosed ApplicationName.
Therefore the batch file will restart `ApplicationName.bat` instead of `ApplicationName.exe`